# Android WebView will not display a local HTML file. Logs "ImeThread is not enabled"

Tags: java, android, html, webview

WebView keeps on displaying a completely white screen. It works with websites like Google and Reddit, but will not display a local html file.

This is my code:

```
public class Stofmaengdeberegner extends Activity {
private WebView webview;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_stofmaengdeberegner);

    //Webview

    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewFormelStofmaengde);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webview.loadUrl("Test.html");

}
```

It says `ImeThread is not enabled.` and  `validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)` in the log.